# How to count occurrences of parts of datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

I have been trying to find out how to group and count just the years in **datetime2**. The rest of the date does not matter, for as long as it has the same year I want it to be counted and grouped. This is the query I have so far. I tried to get the year of the date in an integer and try my luck using the **count** method, but it will only count it if the date values are exactly the same.

```
DECLARE @user_id [int] =12
SELECT [date],user_id, COUNT(YEAR([date])) as yearCount
from table
where table.user_id = @user_id 
group by date,user_id
```

What the query shows:

```
date                          user_id   yearCount
-------                       -------   -----------
2020-11-12 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
2020-05-23 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
2021-06-01 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
2021-04-15 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
2022-02-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
2022-01-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          1
```

What I would like it to look like:

```
date                          user_id   yearCount
-------                       -------   -----------
2020-11-12 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2020-05-23 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2021-06-01 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2021-04-15 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2022-02-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2022-01-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the windowed version of `count()` and partition by the year (and optional the user ID -- you can also omit this, if you really only ever include exactly one user ID in the result).

```
SELECT date,
       user_id,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year(date),
                                   user_id) yearcount
       FROM elbat
       WHERE user_id = @user_id;
```

Comment: That totally did it! Thank you!

Comment: @sticky bit    How would you do this if I was trying to put the yearCount into a variable? What I also wanted to ask was if I were to make a query that took an integer like 2021 and it put it in the variable yearCount, what would that look like? I made the mistake of not getting saying the question I wanted to ask (yes i'm dumb) Should I edit this or make a new question?

Comment: @scarp: That's a new question, this one is answered.