# Data retrieval to regular variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

So my previous question about counting the occurrences of parts of datetime2 left me with a couple questions. [How to count occurrences of parts of datetime2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556066/how-to-count-occurrences-of-parts-of-datetime2)

The final format of my last question is

```
date                          user_id   yearCount
-------                       -------   -----------
2020-11-12 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2020-05-23 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2021-06-01 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2021-04-15 00:00:00.0000000     12          2
2022-02-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          3
2022-01-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          3
2022-04-20 00:00:00.0000000     12          3
```

Which was created by *@sticky bit*

```
SELECT date,
       user_id,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year(date),
                                   user_id) yearcount
       FROM table
       WHERE user_id = @user_id;
```

What I would like to figure out now is, if I was making a query how would I get the yearCount for a specific year into a variable? Lets say I wanted to query only the year 2022(int). So after the query is done I would like a variable *(lets just say @yearCountAmount)* to have the value of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use aggregation:

```
SELECT @yearcount = COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE user_id = @user_id AND
      YEAR(date) = 2022;
```

I might also suggest writing the date logic as:

```
SELECT @yearcount = COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE user_id = @user_id AND
      date >= '2022-01-01' AND
      date < '2023-01-01';
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code, you would pass in the user_id and the year and it would return the variable yearCountAmount. I altered the code you originally had to replace the logic for count and created a case statement encapsulated by SUM.

```
DECLARE @user_id int = 12
DECLARE @Year INT = 2022
DECLARE @yearCountAmount INT

SET @yearCountAmount = (SELECT SUM(case when YEAR(date) = @year then 1 end) 
                        FROM table
                        WHERE user_id = @user_id
                           AND YEAR(date) = @Year)

SELECT @yearCountAmount
```

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY user_id` when you already have `WHERE user_id = @user_id` ?

Comment: @Squirrel you're right, I didn't need the group by since it is already in the where. I fixed my code. Thanks!